# MySQL Proc OrderBy Case Not Allowing More Than One Column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case

I have a proc that needs to order the query by different fields depending on a parameter. To accomplish this I have created a simple case statement for my `ORDER BY` command which works great until I add a second sort field. I'm sure it's just a syntax issue, but I can't seem to find anything on this issue.

```
  ORDER BY 
    CASE _sort 
      WHEN 'random' THEN RAND() 
      WHEN 'latest' THEN u.updated, ut.sort
      WHEN 'alpha' THEN u.pageTitle, ut.sort 
      ELSE ut.sort 
    END
   ASC
  LIMIT _limit;
```

Adding the `, ut.sort` to each `WHEN` is what throws the error. When removed the proc works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE _sort WHEN 'random' THEN RAND() 
               WHEN 'latest' THEN u.updated
               WHEN 'alpha' THEN u.pageTitle
               ELSE 1
               END, ut.sort
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but unfortunately I was just adding ut.sort as an example. The second (and sometimes third) fields are not always the sort field. It is different for each WHEN statement.